# How to rename all (sub)directories and files on Linux CentOS 7

Tags: linux, rename, file-rename

How to rename all (sub)directories and files on Linux CentOS 7?
I tried this command but it didn't work:

```
find Files -depth | xargs -n 1 rename -v ‘s/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/$1\/\L$2/’ {} \;
```

Comment: The apostrophes `‘` and `’` are incorrect. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck).

Answer (score 0):

First problem: You used smart quotes in the xargs operation i.e. the command:

```
xargs -n 1 rename -v ‘s/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/$1\/\L$2/’ {} \;
```

was never going to work. Smart quotes are invalid characters in the shell. The presence of the `{} \;` seems to indicate you were re-doing a `find -exec`, which is completely not needed in this case, so the xargs can be replaced by:

```
xargs -n 1 rename -v 's/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/$1\/\L$2/'
```

Adding in a `-n` for test purposes, it displays a bunch of upper -> lower renames on files on my file system, so it does appear to be doing the right thing now.

My suggested rewrite:

```
find Files -depth -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 rename -v 's/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/$1\/\L$2/'
```

Should accomplish what you're trying, as well as to attempt to avoid issues involving files with spaces in them.

without the `-print0` / `-0`, if I do:

```
touch "common/this is EVIL"
```

then the operations would show that it will not rename this file, whereas if I use the `-print0`/`-0` it shows that:

```
rename(common/this is EVIL, common/this is evil)
```